# Grails: How do you retrieve the UserDetails object from a controller?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 1.3.7. I have a custom `UserDetails` object that gets created in my `customUserDetailsService` during authentication. I assume that this custom `UserDetails` object is then stored in the session somewhere. However, I cannot find how to retrieve it.

I thought that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()` would do it, but that returns an object of type: `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails`, and not my custom UserDetails.

Comment: So Steve's answer is correct, but I have a confession to make. I didn't include all the details of what I was doing in my original question. I've actually provided my own custom AuthenticationProvider. From that provider I was returning a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken object, in which I placed the username (as a string), the password, and the authorities. I had then provided my own UserDetailsService, because I thought that was the way to get my custom UserDetails into the session.

Comment: Anyway, to make a long story short, I finally figured out that I could pass my custom UserDetails object as the first argument to the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken constructor. This is what makes the call to springSecurityService.principal work. I hope this helps someone else who might be struggling with the same issue I had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using 2.0.4 and spring security plugin, it kind of looks like you are using the plugin?

If so try:

```
// Inject 
def springSecurityService

// Action
def index() { 
  UserDetails currentUser = springSecurityService.principal 
}
```